# Ember data: Insert new item at beginning of array instead of at the end

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my application I'm displaying a timeline of messages. We retrieve them from the server in descending chronological order, newest to oldest.

```
3 - Howdy
2 - Greetings
1 - Mahalo
```

Our users also have the ability to add a new message which by default gets inserted at the end of the queue like so

```
3 - Howdy
2 - Greetings
1 - Mahalo
4 - I'm the new message, last as usual
```

When I submit, I'd like new messages to show up at the top. I've written a function before that reverses the array of items, but that wouldn't work for items already in the array.

```
4 - I'm the new message, first finally
3 - Howdy
2 - Greetings
1 - Mahalo
```

What would be the best approach in this case? The ideal would be for Ember Data to prepend to the content array rather than append. Is there another option which might be better?

Comment: is this model defined with a `created_at` property or any other timestamp-like property? with the [SortableMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html) you should be able to define `sortProperty: 'createdAt'` or some other property, like Id for example. This is already baked into the `ArrayController`. If you can't use this for sorting, you'd have to define a property which holds the id of the message you want to prepend, or a computed prop which you manually re-order your `content`

Comment: If you don't want to use the SortableMixin, you could also set up a computed property that observes `@each` or even `length` and sort based on that.

Comment: Joe, is that built in? I looked at it earlier and that seems like a good solution. Could it really be that easy?

Comment: @commadelimited if you're still not sure, take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/tbbAe/). I think this should work for you if you have a way to filter by a timestamp type of property

Comment: Thiago, amazing. Thank you. Could you please post that as an answer and I'll mark that as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most scenarios involving sorting it's recommented to use [`Ember.SortableMixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html), which is baked into [`Ember.ArrayController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html).

Please refer to this conceptual example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/tbbAe/

In this sample the model has a `DateTime` field named `when`, which I'm using for filtering:

```
App.Greeting = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    when: DS.attr('date')                  
});

App.Greeting.FIXTURES = [
    {id: 1, text: 'First', when: '3/4/2013 2:44:52 PM'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Second', when: '3/4/2013 2:44:52 PM'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Third', when: '3/4/2013 2:44:52 PM'},
    {id: 4, text: 'Fourth', when: '3/4/2013 3:44:52 PM'}
];
```

In the controller the only thing I have to do is to set the name of the property and the sorting direction:

```
App.SortingMixinController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['when'],
    sortAscending: false
});
```

Then in my Handlebars template, I can use the `{{each}}` helper as I would do normally.

Because in this sample, all the dates are the same except for the *Forth* (which because of sorting appears first), and also because of `SortableMixin`, these values will be sorted through another property - I'm assuming the Id here.

The other approach I've taken in that fiddle is using a computed property. I'm not really sure about that approach as it seems to consume more resources and the code in `App.SortingPropertyController` is worthy of laugh, but sort of works to show possibilities.

Comment: Voted. On a side, but related note, your Fiddle isn't working. When I view it in Chrome, I get console errors stating that the mime type of the scripts are text/plain instead of executable. I got it to work by saving the content locally...but thought you might want to look at it.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not getting any issues/messages on Chrome for both Mac and Win8. I'll try to reproduce in the other computer. What SO are you running?

Comment: OS X 10.7.5, Chrome 26.0.1410.19. Interesting. My work computer has troubles, but I don't have them here at home.

Answer (score -4):

Can you use basic JavaScript to drop in the new item at a given location in the array? Not sure if this is basic ajax + js objects or full blown ember-data models but this works for the simple js array example

```
 var arr = [];
 arr[0] = "Jani";
 arr[1] = "Hege";
 arr[2] = "Stale";
 arr[3] = "Kai Jim";
 arr[4] = "Borge";

 console.log(arr.join());
 arr.splice(2, 0, "Lene");
 console.log(arr.join());
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
Jani,Hege,Stale,Kai Jim,Borge
Jani,Hege,Lene,Stale,Kai Jim, Borge
```

Comment: Yeah. I could manually prepend a post, but that would mean it'd be on the page twice. Once manually, and another time from Ember data. Or are you talking about moving it from the bottom to the top with DOM manipulation?

Comment: ah -the sortable mixin might be your best bet then (sorry for the half baked answer)