# EmberJS pushing new record to top of list

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my EmberJS application, I sort my records from the backend itself, in descending order of a property `createdAt`. But when I create a new record, it appears at the bottom of the list instead of the top, until I reload the page.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210249/ember-data-insert-new-item-at-beginning-of-array-instead-of-at-the-end/15235300#15235300) seems to use a deprecated API and I'm unable to accomplish this functionality using computed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Ember.computed.sort()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort):

```
sortedItems: Ember.computed.sort('items', (l, r) => get(l, 'createdAt') > get(r, 'createdAt'))
```

Or do it by hand. Either use [`Ember.Enumerable.SortBy`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_sortBy) or plain Javascript `Array.sort`:

```
sortedItems: Ember.computed('items.@each.createdAt', {
  get() {
    // maybe use Ember.Enumerable.SortBy
    return get(this, 'items').sortBy('createdAt');
    // or plain javascript
    return get(this, 'items').sort((l,r) => get(l, 'createdAt') > get(r, 'createdAt'));
  }
})
```